# How to clear swap file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, swapfile

I have a Digital Ocean droplet on which running `free -h` shows the following:

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.9G        3.1G        735M         44K         64M        651M
Swap:          3.0G        3.0G        164K
```

The swapfile is full and I want to empty it. All answers I've found on the internet suggest to turn off the swap and then turn it on using `sudo swapoff -a`. However, when I run this command, I get:

```
swapoff: /swapfile: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

I've searched for this issue as well and the suggestion here is to clear the caches, but clearing caches has no effect. I cannot turn off the swap, I cannot create a new swap, I cannot delete the swap file. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Thanks to that swapfile the kernel is allocating more than available RAM, when you try to disable the swap then the kernel has not enough RAM to move the pages out of it, hence the error message. You can't make that memory disappear, it has to go somewhere.